# How to build trust as a new company?

Tags: software-industry, work-environment, startup, teamwork, tech-industry

just curious... how companies `build trust` to other companies to offer services(cybersecurity) when your employees don't have certifications, but they are powerful employees. let's take the case of `Google, Facebook`.

> why small companies or less big tech doesn't work this complex strategy?
>   how to make to work this strategy on new companies?

- would it work as employees contributing to the infosec community, and writeups, GitHub tools, etc?
- is it possible to achieve this strategy to build trust in companies having powerful, and exceptional employees skills without having certified employees, but train them with courses?

Comment: I don't own a company, but I just wanted to know why small companies cant take the same model as Google or Facebook?

Answer (score 2):

While certifications may not be required, you still need to convince potential clients that your team will be effective. Some sort of professional credentials or other evidence could help.

Think about what makes your employees "powerful and exceptional". Determine what you could offer as verifiable proof of their ability, other than just your words.

Testimonials from satisfied clients are often effective. Sometimes a free trial period can demonstrate ability, as could a money-back guarantee. Publications are a common way to demonstrate competence. Presentations at industry conferences can show mastery of a topic.

Comment: I might add: think specifically about what you want your reputation to be, and focus your effort on building that reputation. For example, "zmrdim and company are great at planning and delivering scalable  backend projects on time,"

Comment: @O.Jones that's exactly want to achieve beyond the certifications and spread the word. the x team from zmrdim company has the most lethal team talking about in terms of capability

Answer (score 1):

The only way to accomplish this is to have personal connections with the company. Either through a professional network where your company and employees are known. Or friends or relatives.

It is actually reasonably common in some locales, more common than not many places, but more so with govt than the private sector in my experience. But it's also fairly common anywhere for relatives or close friends of a companies owners to get lucrative contracts despite not having the best or qualified services.

Sometimes a company will hire an executive or project manager, just because this person has the professional or personal contacts to get them the contract(s) they want.

Comment: Bribery should be in the list - not legal but seems to still happen...

Comment: @SolarMike yep, in the biggest companies anywhere, not necessarily bribery, but kickbacks are common enough

Answer (score 0):

There is really one way how a small company can make a big company trust it: If you have contracts where violating that trust means the people at the head of the company are going to pay for it.

Comment: what do you mean? add more context